# GPUImageiOSBlurFilter imageByFilteringImage: returns nil

Tags: ios, gpuimage

spent some time and can't really understand where is a problem.

I'm using GPUImage 0.1.3 (from CocoaPods) and have very straightforward code:

```
GPUImageiOSBlurFilter *iosBlur = [[GPUImageiOSBlurFilter alloc] init];
UIImage *splashScreenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash"];
UIImage *bluredImage = [iosBlur imageByFilteringImage:splashScreenImage];
```

bluredImage is nil.
I stepped through the code, iosBlur isn't nil, splashScreenImage isn't nil and contains proper image (checked in debugger's quick view). So I don't have any idea where is a problem.

Comment: Cant you step into 'imageByFilteringImage' and check why it returns nil?

Comment: I can step into, but I was lost there a bit when it started using GCD etc.. Too many steps in. It is pretty straightforward case and I thought may be someone have an answer other than debug GPUImage (it is a decent code, but isn't very easy to understand for me).

Comment: Try to change the filter settings like:         iosBlur.blurRadiusInPixels = 2.;

Comment: Tried that already...

Comment: Try using the latest code from the repository. I fixed a few things with filter groups (like this filter) after I added the 0.1.3 tag. I may retag this once I fix a couple other things.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll give it a try. Behaviour is really strange. `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter` used to work but after changes in other classes (completely different part of the code) it stopped working. Same problem - `imageByFilteringImage` returns `nil`.

Comment: It is very likely that some mandatory files are missing in CocoaPods. After overriding framework from latest github version it works perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I worked around it - crude, but works.
BTW - this still happens with the latest code of GPUImage, although I mostly see the issue in the simulator.

```
    int errorCount = 0;
    UIImage *blurImage;
    //Loop workaround for some unknown GPUImage issue where sometimes the result is nil.
    while (! (blurImage = [imageFilter imageByFilteringImage:image]) ) {
        ++errorCount;
    }

    if (errorCount > 0) {
        NSLog(@"GPUImageiOSBlurFilter imageByFilteringImage error count: %i", errorCount);
    }
```

Comment: I have seen a similar issue using GPUImageCannyEdgeDetectionFilter. As far as I can tell it also only happens on the simulator. This solution fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the GPUImageOutput.h

```
// Platform-specific image output methods
// If you're trying to use these methods, remember that you need to set -useNextFrameForImageCapture 
// before running -processImage or running video and calling any of these methods, 
// or you will get a nil image
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
- (UIImage *)imageByFilteringImage:(UIImage *)imageToFilter;
```

Comment: As far as I understand, it's unrelated to this specific issue. As usually two consecutive calls fixes the issue, and further more the issue only happen on the simulator.